# What happens when you help the "fake" Rachni queen?

Tags: mass-effect-3

This has been bugging me, if you choose to save the fake Rachni queen, does she help you? I can't find her in my war assets. Or does she just disapear?

Comment: Well...I'm f*cked.I did it only because of the Renegade

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At some point you will get a message that she has betrayed you and you lose the war asset. The [Mass Effect 3 wiki](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Rachni_Queen#Mass_Effect_3) also says she will do some damage to your Alliance Engineering Corps but I did not follow my war assets closely enough to see that happen.

Choosing to save her is a -125 war asset difference compared to not saving her.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't have saved the artificial Rachni queen, She will betray you and kill some of you engineers working on the crucible, reducing the Alliance Engineering Corps war asset value.

> If the rachni queen was killed in the first Mass Effect, then in Mass Effect 3 the Reapers will construct an artificial queen so they can have a rachni army to turn into Ravagers. If Shepard chooses to free this queen then, unlike the queen from Noveria, this artificial queen eventually proves untrustworthy after a few missions, taking away the rachni workers war asset she gave at first and sharply reducing the Alliance Engineering Corps.

[Link](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Attican_Traverse:_Krogan_Team#Outcome)