# Is there a reason for the Artificial Rachni queens action?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I had saved the Artificial Rachni Queen and gotten her as a war asset, but at some point there was a small notice saying that she had betrayed me and I lost the war asset. I can not seam to find any other information on her betrayal than the small popup saying she had done it.

Is there no other mention of her betrayal than the pop up notifying that you lost the war asset?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/56603 Note that this [doesn't happen](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Rachni_Queen#Mass_Effect_3) if you save the Rachni Queen in ME1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another mention in an update to the Alliance Engineering Corps War Asset:

> UPDATE
>
> The last reports from the AEC were little more than officers screaming about rachni flooding into their barracks, scything through unsuspecting scientists. After a brave, but brief, battle, the core of the Alliance Engineering Corps was wiped out by their traitorous alien "allies."

This also results in a -100 penalty for that War Asset.

Comment: thanks, is the -100 including the loose of Rachni war asset or on top of it?

Comment: @Blem: Yes, this is in addition to losing the Rachni, as well as the -25 to Aralakh company and possible loss of Grunt (if not loyal) when saving her. Ultimately, trusting the artificial queen turns out to be a really bad idea.